# automatically entering passphrase in openssl command

Tags: bash, openssl, expect

I'm writing a script that automatically enters the user's input for an openssl command, but I can't find a way of entering the required passphrase automatically by the script. What I've tried:

```
spawn sudo openssl x509 -req -in client.csr -CA /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/ca.crt -CAkey /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/ca.key -CAcreateserial -out client.crt -days 15; 
expect 'Enter pass phrase for /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/ca.key:'
send '1234\n'
```

Doesn't work (spawn and send not found)

```
printf '1234\n' | sudo openssl x509 -req -in client.csr -CA /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/ca.crt -CAkey /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/ca.key -CAcreateserial -out client.crt -days 15;
```

Doesn't work, stays waiting for the passphrase and programs never finishes, unless I enter '1234' manually.

In other cases, it works with printf:

```
printf 'ES\n\n\n\n\nclient'$n'\n\n\n\n' | sudo openssl req -out client.csr -key client.key -new;
```

My guess is that printf doesn't work if the input it's hidden. Any ideas?

Comment: *"spawn and send not found"* `spawn` and `send` are commands of the `expect` language - you would need to run this inside an `expect` script rather than inside a `bash` shell script

Answer (score 2):

Found a way of doing it without using expect:

You basically need to include `--passin pass:'your_passphrase'` in the command

For example: `sudo openssl x509 -req -in client.csr -CA /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/ca.crt -CAkey /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/ca.key -CAcreateserial -out client.crt --passin pass:1234 -days 15;`

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30426586/how-to-specify-ca-private-key-password-for-client-certificate-creation-using-ope)

There are other ways of doing it, such as loading a password file, which is more secure, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294689/how-to-generate-an-openssl-key-using-a-passphrase-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

The process that creates a password protected key file needs a password which gets used to store this **output** file. So, the `-passin` argument you use is for reading an **input** file. From the [documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/req.html):

> -passin arg - The input file password source.

Instead you need the proper option to specify the output password, i.e.

> -passout arg - The output file password source.

In this case to open the `/etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/ca.key` key you need this:

```bsh
sudo openssl x509 \
-passin pass:'1234' \
-req \
-in client.csr \
-CA /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/ca.crt \
-CAkey /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/ca.key 
-CAcreateserial \
-out client.crt \
-days 15
```